# I have this problem : Failed to compile values file

Tags: java, android, android-studio, intellij-idea

I cant build my app becaause of this error .
I ve cleared the project and rebuilded it  , invalided the cache
but nothing workked can you help me ?

I have also deleted the cache in .gradle folder but nothing worked

Here is  the log  ,  thanks in advance

```
     2021-06-09 00:40:55,442 [9449369]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Android Studio 4.2.1  Build #AI-202.7660.26.42.7351085 
2021-06-09 00:40:55,442 [9449369]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - JDK: 11.0.8; VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM; Vendor: N/A 
2021-06-09 00:40:55,442 [9449369]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - OS: Windows 10 
2021-06-09 00:40:55,442 [9449369]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Last Action: $Undo 
2021-06-09 00:40:55,447 [9449374]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Element: class com.intellij.psi.impl.source.tree.java.PsiReferenceExpressionImpl #JAVA  because: containing file is null; hierarchy=,class com.intellij.psi.impl.source.tree.java.PsiExpressionListImplclass com.intellij.psi.impl.source.tree.java.PsiMethodCallExpressionImplclass com.intellij.psi.impl.source.tree.java.PsiExpressionListImplclass com.intellij.psi.impl.source.tree.java.PsiMethodCallExpressionImplclass com.intellij.psi.impl.source.tree.java.PsiReferenceExpressionImplclass com.intellij.psi.impl.source.tree.java.PsiMethodCallExpressionImplclass com.intellij.psi.impl.source.tree.java.PsiReferenceExpressionImplclass com.intellij.psi.impl.source.tree.java.PsiMethodCallExpressionImplclass com.intellij.psi.impl.source.tree.java.PsiLocalVariableImplclass com.intellij.psi.impl.source.tree.java.PsiDeclarationStatementImpl, context=null, contextFile=null
invalidated at: see attachment 
com.intellij.psi.PsiInvalidElementAccessException: Element: class com.intellij.psi.impl.source.tree.java.PsiReferenceExpressionImpl #JAVA  because: containing file is null; hierarchy=,class com.intellij.psi.impl.source.tree.java.PsiExpressionListImplclass com.intellij.psi.impl.source.tree.java.PsiMethodCallExpressionImplclass com.intellij.psi.impl.source.tree.java.PsiExpressionListImplclass com.intellij.psi.impl.source.tree.java.PsiMethodCallExpressionImplclass com.intellij.psi.impl.source.tree.java.PsiReferenceExpressionImplclass com.intellij.psi.impl.source.tree.java.PsiMethodCallExpressionImplclass com.intellij.psi.impl.source.tree.java.PsiReferenceExpressionImplclass com.intellij.psi.impl.source.tree.java.PsiMethodCallExpressionImplclass com.intellij.psi.impl.source.tree.java.PsiLocalVariableImplclass com.intellij.psi.impl.source.tree.java.PsiDeclarationStatementImpl, context=null, contextFile=null
invalidated at: see attachment
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.tree.CompositePsiElement.getContainingFile(CompositePsiElement.java:106)
    at com.intellij.openapi.module.ModuleUtilCore.findModuleForPsiElement(ModuleUtilCore.java:77)
    at com.android.tools.idea.AndroidPsiUtils.lambda$getModuleSafely$2(AndroidPsiUtils.java:104)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:857)
    at com.android.tools.idea.AndroidPsiUtils.getModuleSafely(AndroidPsiUtils.java:104)
    at org.jetbrains.android.facet.AndroidFacet.getInstance(AndroidFacet.java:56)
    at org.jetbrains.android.AndroidAnnotatorUtil$ColorRenderer.getIcon(AndroidAnnotatorUtil.java:332)
    at com.intellij.openapi.editor.impl.EditorGutterComponentImpl.processIconsRowForY(EditorGutterComponentImpl.java:1134)
    at com.intellij.openapi.editor.impl.EditorGutterComponentImpl.paintIconRow(EditorGutterComponentImpl.java:1024)
    at com.intellij.openapi.editor.impl.EditorGutterComponentImpl.paintIcons(EditorGutterComponentImpl.java:979)
    at com.intellij.openapi.editor.impl.EditorGutterComponentImpl.paintGutterRenderers(EditorGutterComponentImpl.java:968)
    at com.intellij.openapi.editor.impl.EditorGutterComponentImpl.paintLineMarkers(EditorGutterComponentImpl.java:517)
    at com.intellij.openapi.editor.impl.EditorGutterComponentImpl.paintComponent(EditorGutterComponentImpl.java:371)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1077)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5263)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBufferedImpl(RepaintManager.java:1654)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(RepaintManager.java:1629)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1566)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1333)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(JComponent.java:5211)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(JComponent.java:5021)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(RepaintManager.java:868)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(RepaintManager.java:851)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:851)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:826)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:775)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1901)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:313)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:776)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:727)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:746)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:971)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:841)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$null$8(IdeEventQueue.java:452)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computePrioritized(CoreProgressManager.java:744)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$9(IdeEventQueue.java:451)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:495)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

Comment: Have you updated the dependencies through `Gradle`?